# Multiprocess pool.map() stops after the first set of inputs

Tags: python, keras, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use pool.map() to serialise a function, which takes one single input and writes the output to a csv file. It seems that the process stops after the first set of inputs. I'm running the code on Debian with 4 cores.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from keras.models import load_model
input = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
model = load_model(directory)
def func(input):
    # some calculations
    prediction = model.predict(data)
    # more calculations
    print('Currently working on', input)
    df.to_csv(directory)

def main():
    workers = cpu_count()
    pool = Pool(processes=workers)
    pool.map(func, input)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    main()
    print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

```
Currently working on 1
Currently working on 2
Currently working on 3
Currently working on 4
```

I'm getting the above output, and then it doesn't go on to the subsequent inputs. I've tested the function without multiprocessing, and it works fine, so I am guessing the problem sits somewhere in `Pool()`.

Edit:
After some debug I found the problem. I am using a Keras model as part of the function, and that seemed to be where the issue is.

Comment: The code works for me if I replace your `df.to_csv()` call with `time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))`, so I think the problem has to do with your use of a pandas `dataframe`, not `Pool`.

Comment: @martineau Just tested with `df.to_csv()` and it works here.. (python 3.6). I have 8 cores, tested with 30 inputs and it goes all the way. @Winston, you get no exception, no output from that `print()` on your `main()`, the program doesn't hang and ends successfully (result code = 0)?

Comment: @Alexandre Juma, strange. I get nothing and the program just pauses after the first four prints. My actual function is much more complicated so maybe that's the reason. But I did test the function many times without multiprocess to make sure it is working properly.

Comment: Maybe you have stuff in your function that isn't safe to paralelize and it's breaking your program. Even not knowing what your function does, one thing you can do is try out the other `map()` implementations. You can try `pool.imap(func, input)`, `pool.map_async(func, input)`, `pool.imap_unordered(func, input)`. Long shot!

Comment: I seem to have found the issue, which has to do with calling a keras model during the function, which as some pointed out, is not safe to parallelise.

Comment: Great! Answer your own question for others to benefit from it :)